# Creating a shared folder using C#

Tags: c#, windows

I've spent the last few days scouring the site looking for an answer to this problem,
i need to create a folder and then make it a shared networked folder, I've tried several different sample code snippets from different sites

http://www.sarampalis.org/articles/dotnet/dotnet0002.shtml (this link is dead)

but none seem to allow the folder to be shared

If anyone could be of help it'd be much aprriciated

Comment: Can you specify how this method failed? Did you get some access denied exception? Or some other exception? Maybe this failed because you were not running as an admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did follow the link that you have in your question.

I have a Win 7 Professional + VS.NET 2010 Professional as my dev environment on my laptop.

I took the code from the article and quickly fired up a devenv and executed the code. The code executed perfectly without any error. When i looked at the created directory you dont see a share icon on the folder but it is indeed shared. How can you check that: 
open a command prompt
type "net share" and press enter
you will see that it will list the folder c:\MyTestShare with a share name "My Test Share"

One more way to find out whether it is shared or not is to right click on the folder and look at the sharing tab. Check the Network Path label. It will clearly show the shared path.

Hope this helps you.
Lohith

Comment: Thanks Lohith, i retried this code on my home network and it worked first time, I've tracked the issue to permissions on our servers not allowing super users to create folders on the servers

Answer (score 2):

If you don't find the real Windows API that does this, and you can settle for a dirty solution, you can do it by executing the command "net share".

For example, like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("net", "share MyNewShare=c:\\folder");
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
Process.Start(info);
```

Note that in any case, in order to create a share you need administrative rights, so your code will have to run elevated if you're running on Win7/Vista with UAC enabled.

Comment: Sometimes dirty solutions are all that is required.

Answer (score 0):

See

http://www.sarampalis.org/articles/dotnet/dotnet0002.shtml

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/Share-Folder-c_.aspx

Comment: I think Scott already mentioned one of those sites in the original post.  I put the other, but then after looking at the sarampalis link, I deleted it because it is basically the same thing.  Obviously if Scott has tried this method and it does not work, neither of them will work.

Comment: Thanks for the help the issues where to do with our servers not the code